# Source for "Bein Ish L'Ishto" in Nusach Ari

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, provenance, maseches-shabbos, nusach-ari

After the morning bracha on the torah, we say "אלו דברים שאין להם שיעור".  The source for this text is a combination of the [first mishna of Peah](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%94_%D7%90_%D7%90), and some additions from [the bottom of Shabbat 127a](http://halakhah.com/shabbath/shabbath_127.html).

I recently noticed that in Nusach Ari, there's a further addition made:

והבאת שלום בין אדם לחברו  **ובין איש לאשתו**

I was wondering if anyone knows the original source for adding these words, or if there is any rabbinic authority on why it was deemed necessary to add them.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WHY Nusach Ari adds these last words, but phylosphically, a person's wife is an extension of a "friendship", and is actually on a higher level. If there's a mitzvah to bring peace between one and his neighbor, moreso between man and wife. While this SHOULD be the case, sadly we see too many situations where people treat their friends BETTER than their wives. Thus, it's good that this is added, if for no other reason to remind people of its importance.

Comment: Fwiw _nusach "S'farad"_ adds this too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a book called שער הכולל that aims to explain the choices made in that version of the siddur. The author notes the following in regard to the phrase ובין איש לאשתו ([chapter 1, paragraph 19](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16002&st=&pgnum=24)):

> במשנה שלפנינו לא נמצאו התיבת הללו אבל בסדר היום ובשער השמים משל״ה
>   מביאים הלשון הזה גם בתד״א פי״ג לענין אהרן הכהן מביא זה הלשון בין אדם
>   לחבירו ובין איש לאשתו
>
> In the text of the Mishnah as we have it, these words are not found.
>   However, in *Seder HaYom* and in *Sha'ar HaShamayim* by the Shla"h
>   these words are included. Also, in *Tana Devei Eliyahu*, chapter 13,
>   regarding Aaron the priest, this wording is used.

Answer (score 3):

The extant manuscripts do not have that addition (see [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/mishpat-ivri/skirot/54-2.htm) footnote 8) however, there are [many variations](http://www.ketershemtob.com/peah1-1hebrew.html) on this saying. It is apparently very common to have that addition in Edut HaMizrachi Nusachos, in addition to Nusach Sfard and Nusach Ari.

The Arizal ascribes a specific [Kabbalistic meaning](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/zz/oht/otb4/4/5/8) to the two parts.